# How do I correctly play a song from MPMediaPicker in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, ipad

Later in my code when I am setting `Sliders`, etc. it returns the **SIGABRT** error saying I can't set a slider's maximum value to NaN, leading me to believe I have done something wrong in my `mediaPicker` code. I don't believe I did everything correctly when importing a file from `MPMediaPicker` to `AVPlayer` with the `URL`. Also, I need to optimize my `mediaPicker` so it only needs code for one song, rather than using the for loop just for one song. Please help.

```
func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {

    for song in mediaItemCollection.items as [MPMediaItem] {
        let url = song.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? NSURL

        let audioItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url! as URL)
        audioPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: audioItem)

        playItem(item: audioItem)
    }

    mediaPicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Use `AVAudioPlayer` instead of `AVPlayer` for song. I think you set the value of `slider.maximumValue` as `audioItem.value` divided by `audioItem.timescale` which result in NaN when both are 0s. Just make slider min value to 0 and max value to 1. Multiply slider's current value with `AVAudioPlayer.duration` and set `AVAudioPlayer.current`. You will be able to wind and unwind your audio playback with ease.